# Does Bookstack support non-local databases?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services

I am trying to set up a Bookstack instance on an EC2 instance and use an RDS instance as the DB. However, all of the existing documentation out there has examples using localhost for the DB.

Bookstack gives you a .env file where it asks for DB_HOST and DB_DATABASE. For Host I entered the RDS endpoint for my db with the port number, and for DB_DATABASE I gave it the name of the DB. When I run `php artisan migrate` per the instructions, I get the following errors:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'my-bookstack-db' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = my-bookstack-db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'my-bookstack-db'
```

Everything I've found so far seems to point to a cache problem, but I don't think that's the case since this is initial setup. I think I'm not giving Bookstack the information it needs, but I don't know what else it is looking for.

Comment: Did you create the my-bookstack-db database?

Comment: This is an SQL error, not a PHP one. The client is connecting just fine, you just need to create the DB before running the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Should just be a matter of running `php artisan db` to start a CLI session to the db.

Once you get a prompt type `CREATE DATABASE my-bookstack-db`

Comment: Not quite. Ran that and it gave me a 127 exit code. It can't connect